# Estimator of $\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu (1 - \mu)}$ when sampling without replacement

Tags: variance, estimation, unbiased-estimator

## Question

Consider a population of known size $N$, from which we sample $n$ individuals without replacement and measure their trait values $x_i$ for all individual $i$. The variable $x$ is bounded `[0,1]`.

Let $\mu = \frac{\sum_i^N x_i}{N}$ be the average trait value in the population and $\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_i^N (x_i - \mu)^2}{N}$ be the variance in the population.

**What is the unbiased estimator for $\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu (1 - \mu)}$?**

---

## Attempt

I got estimators for both the numerator ($\sigma^2$) and denominator ($\mu (1-\mu)$).

**First few definitions**

First let

$$\bar x = \frac{\sum_i^n x_i}{n}$$

and

$$s^2 = \frac{\sum_i^n (x_i - \bar x)^2}{n-1}$$

**Numerator**

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389735/unbiased-estimator-of-the-variance-with-known-population-size), the unbiased estimator for $\sigma^2$ is

$$\sigma^2 = \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{(N-1)s^2}{N}\right]$$

**Denominator**

The unbiased estimator of $\mu - \mu^2$ is

$$ \begin{align}
\mu - \mu^2
&= \operatorname{E}[\bar x] - \operatorname{E}[\bar x]^2\\
&= \operatorname{E}[\bar x] - \operatorname{E}[\bar x]^2 - \operatorname{var}[\bar X] + \operatorname{var}[\bar x] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[\bar x] - \operatorname{E}[\bar x^2] + \operatorname{var}[\bar x] 
\end{align}$$

From [utexas](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/parker/sampling/woreplshort.htm)

$$ \operatorname{var}[\bar X] = \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{s^2}{n}\left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right)\right]$$

Therefore,

$$\mu - \mu^2 = \operatorname{E}\left[\bar x - \bar x^2 + \frac{s^2}{n}\left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right)\right]$$

**Putting numerator and denominator together**

If the two estimators were independent, then the product of the expectations would be the expectation of the product but the numerator is not independent of the denominator!

I suppose I would now need to compute something like

$$
 \begin{align}
\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu (1 - \mu)} &= \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{\frac{(N-1)s^2}{N}}{\bar x - \bar x^2 + \frac{s^2}{n}\left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right)} + \operatorname{cov}\left[\operatorname{var}\left[x\right], \frac{1}{\bar x - \bar x^2}\right]\right] \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{\frac{(N-1)s^2}{N}}{\bar x - \bar x^2 + \frac{s^2}{n}\left(1-\frac{n}{N}\right)}\right] + \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{\operatorname{var}\left[x\right]}{\bar x - \bar x^2}\right] - \operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{var}\left[x\right]\right]\operatorname{E}\left[\frac{1}{\bar x - \bar x^2}\right]\\
\end{align}
$$

but I am getting lost there!

Comment: The very appearance of $1/(\mu(1-\mu))$, with its singularities at $\{0,1\}$, suggests a context in which strong assumptions are made about the variable. One would suppose its values are limited to the interval $[0,1]$, for instance.  Could you disclose all such assumptions and perhaps give us some context or motivation for looking at this particular combination of parameters?

Comment: @whuber Yes, applications are in genetics. The variable $x$ are allele frequencies among populations and can take values in the range [0,1] ($\mu - \mu^2$ can therefore take values in the range [0,0.25]). I have added this info to the post! The statistics $\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu-\mu^2}$ is actually quite common (see for example [Nei 1973](http://www.pnas.org/content/70/12/3321.short)).

Comment: Unbiased estimators of nonlinear statistics are extremely rare. You can stumble upon one only by some luck (outside of exponential families with canonical link). I would very seriously doubt that an unbiased estimator for this quantity exists. There won't be any shortage of consistent estimators, and if you simply have the plug-in estimators of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, you can obtain the variance of your statistic by the delta method. I don't see where the finite nature of your population comes into play though -- the finite population corrections matter quantitatively when $n/N>0.1$, say.

Comment: The existence of at least one unbiased estimator cannot assumed; it must be demonstrated. And one certainly cannot assume there is only one.

Comment: If $\Pr(x_i\in\{0,1\}) = 1$ then $\mu(1-\mu)$ is the same thing as $\sigma^2.\qquad$